# ASIO проблема с подключением

Tags: c++, boost, c++17, asio

При попытке запустить в любой версии (релизная либо дебажная) после недолго ожидания вылетатет исключение непонятного содержания (кодировка проекта юникод, стандарт сборки с++17). Пример типовый, из мануалов. Брандмауэр на указанный порт настроил на прием-передачу. Помогите, пожалуйста

Код клиента:

```
#include "TCP_ASIO_Client.h"


using namespace boost::asio;
 
int main()
{
    try
    {
        io_service service;
        ip::tcp::endpoint ep(ip::address::from_string("127.0.0.1"), 2001);
        ip::tcp::socket sock(service);
        sock.connect(ep);
    }
    catch (boost::system::system_error &e)
    {
        std::cout << e.what() << std::endl;
    }
 
    system("pause");
}
```

Код сервера:

```
#include "TCP_ASIO_Server.h"


#include <thread>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>
 
using namespace boost::asio;
typedef boost::shared_ptr<ip::tcp::socket> socket_ptr;
 
void client_session(socket_ptr sock);
 
int main()
{
    try
    {
        io_service service;
        ip::tcp::endpoint ep(ip::tcp::v4(), 2001); // listen on 2001
        ip::tcp::acceptor acc(service, ep);
        while (true)
        {
            socket_ptr sock(new ip::tcp::socket(service));
            acc.accept(*sock);
            std::thread(boost::bind(client_session, sock));
        }
    }
    catch (boost::system::system_error& se)
    {
        std::cout << se.what() << std::endl;
    }
    system("pause");
}
 
void client_session(socket_ptr sock)
{
    while (true)
    {
        char data[512];
        size_t len = sock->read_some(buffer(data));
        if (len > 0)
            write(*sock, buffer("ok", 2));
    }
}
```

Содержание e.what() клиента:
**
connect: ╧юфъы■ўхэшх эх єёЄрэютыхэю, Є.ъ. ъюэхўэ√щ ъюья№■ЄхЁ юЄтхЁу чряЁюё эр яюфъы■ўхэшх [system:10061]
**